# Encrypting database in SQL Server without changing datatype

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am looking for some lightweight encryption algorithm for encrypting a table. I have explained my requirements as below:

**Scenario**: consider just one table in SQL Server for simplicity. After every 3 seconds, data is inserted into the table. Since I look for encryption and decryption in SQL Server, I came across some good links (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)

**Constraint**: according to this article we need to change the datatype of any column where we have to apply encryption to `varbinary` but I don't want to change the datatype of any column (database is already working fine - except for encryption)

So even if I consider this `EncryptByKey` as a simple solution but I don't want to change datatype of all my columns.

Any other suggestion in which I don't have to change the datatypes?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: If you cannot change anything in your SQL Server database - can't you just encrypt the data in your client application and send the **encrypted** data to SQL Server to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

The result of encryption is not a string, it is an array of 8-bit bytes which many bytes are not valid characters in any character encoding. This is the reason for the `varbinary` data type.

The best solution is to change the data type to `varbinary` but if that is not acceptable the work-around is to encode the encryption output to a valid character representation, the two most common are Base64 and hexadecimal. This will of course add some code and time both on addition to the database and retrieval.

Comment: Hi I am trying to work with varbinary. I write the following procedure:

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the current data type of each column is. For something that is already `varchar`, you can just encode the cipher text in Base64 or hexadecimal as zaph said. For a column that needs to maintain a specific format, you'll need to investigate [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) -- for example, [how to encrypt credit card numbers while maintaining the format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).